# Get an adjacent value in JSON array if value is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If I have this type of object returned in javascript (as a result of $get)

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "john"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "username": "bill"
  }
]
```

How would I search for the username "john" and if it exists return his ID

Thanks

i.e.

```
$.get( baseURL + "users/")
  .done(function( data ) {

    var usernames = data.results;

});
```

Comment: There are various ways to do that but we need to know what you've tried first. We could help based on it.

Comment: `arr.find(item => item.name === 'john')`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdI2bqOjy3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find()`:

```js
var array =[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "john"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "username": "bill"
  }
];

var id = array.find(k=>k.username=='john')?.id;

console.log(id);
```